# set fillchars=foldclose:▸ in .vimrc does not work to change '+--' folding characters

Tags: vim, folding

I'm using vim 8.2.

In my .vimrc file I was able to change fold with fillchars successfully:

```
set foldmethod=indent
set fillchars=fold:\
```

But it does not work when I tried with foldopen and foldclose options

```
set fillchars=fold:\ ,foldclose:▸
```

(I tried `set fillchars=foldclose:\▸` without success and
I also tried in some file `:set fillchars=foldclose:▸` with same results)

[image: example]

Can anyone help me?

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot only shows a fold, where the `foldopen` and `foldclose` in `:help 'fillchars'` have no effect. If you want to see them, you will have to enable the `:help 'foldcolumn'`:

[image: example]

If what you actually want is to change that `+--` at the beginning of the fold text, you are supposed to do that with `:help 'foldexpr'`.

Comment: I saw the :help fold-foldtext and it is another way to format fold text that worked for me. Thank you very much.